# Java making vector from 2d array.

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, vector

```
for (i=0; i<=9; i++)
                for (j=0; j<=9; j++) 
                    if (A[i][j]!=0) {
                    B[i] = A[i][j];
            }
            System.out.print("Vector  :   ");
            for(int i1 = 0; i1 < B.length; i1++){
                    System.out.print(B[i1] + " ");
            } array = true;
            System.out.println();
```

I have 10x10 array with 55 values that are different from 0 and i need to make from those 55 numbers one vector.
The problem is that with this code i have, it prints only 10 numbers that are not 0 and other 45 zeros. It takes all values from row 10 and nothing else. 
I think there is something wrong with B[i] but im not sure. Maybe someone can help?

Comment: You're repeatedly reassigning the B[i]th position in the inner loop. You'll need a separate variable to track the current index of B.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from `B[i] = A[i][j];` because `B` must use its own index, `k` for example. Index `i` may be used ten times.

I suggest `B[k++] = A[i][j];`

Answer (score 1):

```
int index = 0 ;
for (i=0; i<=9; i++)
                for (j=0; j<=9; j++) 
                    if (A[i][j]!=0) {
                    B[index] = A[i][j];
                    index++;
            }
            System.out.print("Vector  :   ");
            for(int i1 = 0; i1 < B.length; i1++){
                    System.out.print(B[i1] + " ");
            } array = true;
            System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have a different counter for the vector, as the same `i` gets overriden in your case.

```
for (int i=0, ctr=0; i<=9; i++)
   for (j=0; j<=9; j++) 
      if (A[i][j]!=0) {
          B[ctr++] = A[i][j];
      }
System.out.print("Vector  :   ");
for(int i1 = 0; i1 < B.length; i1++){
    System.out.print(B[i1] + " ");
} array = true;
System.out.println();
```